# Cannot run report in SSRS with connection issue

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I just test my connection of SSRS to the data source, but an error was detected:

[image]

If I run the report, the error goes:

[image]

How can I fix it? "Enable remote error" can not help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This issue is related to data source check connection string for data source 'HarmoniBL' in the report  .

Answer (score 0):

I used to [enable remote errors](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/enable-remote-errors.aspx) on SQL Server Reporting Services using referred methods. But if this did not help you, you can check "[Data Sources](http://www.kodyaz.com/reporting-services/subscriptions-cannot-be-created.aspx)" section for your report including data source connection string and credentials.

During report deployment to Report Server, sometimes the data sources are replaced with ones in development environment. Or if you use connection string specific for each report, developer should edit the connection string after deployment.